Google GSI Client JS CoRS error in salesforce lwc
I am trying to use the Google Picker API in a Lightning Web Component (LWC), and for that, I need to load the Google GIS client JavaScript from the following URL:
Google GIS Client JS.
However, I am encountering an "undefined" error when trying to load this script from static resources. Below is the code I am using:
Code:
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';import apiJs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/googleapi';         // Google API JS (api.js)import clientJs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/googleclient';   // Google Client JS (client.js)import googlescripts from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/googleJS';  // Another JS (optional)export default class GdriveFolderPicker extends LightningElement {    accessToken = null;    pickerInited = false;    gisInited = false;    tokenClient;    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly';    renderedCallback() {        // Loading the scripts        debugger;        Promise.all([            loadScript(this, apiJs)                .then(() => {                    console.log('api.js loaded successfully');                })                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading api.js:', error)),            loadScript(this, clientJs)            .then(() => {                    console.log('client.js loaded successfully');                })                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading client.js:', error))        ])        .then(() => {            // Initialize Google API and GIS client after both scripts are loaded            this.gapiLoaded();            this.gisLoaded();            console.log('Both scripts loaded successfully');        })        .catch(error => {            console.error('Error loading one or more static resources:', error);        });    }    // Additional logic for handling the API loading and initialization    gapiLoaded() {        // Logic for Google API loading    }    gisLoaded() {        // Logic for GIS client loading    }}
Issue 1: Static Resource Loading
The above code attempts to load api.js and client.js from static resources using loadScript. But I am still facing issues. Specifically, I receive an undefined error when loading client.js and other related files. This could be due to incorrect file references or missing dependencies.
Issue 2: CORS Error with Direct Link
Alternatively, I tried loading the Google API JavaScript files using the direct links in the following format:
renderedCallback() {    debugger;    Promise.all([        loadScript(this, 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js')            .then(() => {                console.log('api.js loaded successfully');            })            .catch(error => console.error('Error loading api.js:', error)),        loadScript(this, 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client')            .then(() => {                console.log('client.js loaded successfully');            })            .catch(error => console.error('Error loading client.js:', error))    ])    .then(() => {        // Initialize after both scripts are loaded        this.gapiLoaded();        this.gisLoaded();        console.log('Both scripts loaded successfully');    })    .catch(error => {        console.error('Error loading one or more static resources:', error);    });}
However, when using direct URLs, I encounter CORS errors in the Network tab. Even though I added the URL to the trusted list, it still doesn’t resolve the issue.
